# iOS: Adding array to UITableView - Shows up as one item

Tags: ios, uitableview

The issue I'm running into is I have an NSMutableArray labeled: _podAllEntries, which contains url paths. The contents of this array are then loaded into one row in my UITableView. There are a total of 4 items in this array and there should be an entry in the table per item. Below is a more detailed explination of how the app works:

This iOS app uses NSURL to consume XML data from a website: http://undignified.podbean.com/feed. From there I parse through the XML using NSXMLParser and search for an attribute called "url" within the "enclosure" element. All attributes that match "url" are then added to an array and then should be loaded in the UITableView with each item on a separate row (as previously mentioned, there is only one row filled).

I'm probably missing something minor at this point and a nudge in the right direction or any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

### UnDigParser.h

Header file for parsing class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UnDigParser : NSXMLParser <NSXMLParserDelegate> {

}
@property (retain) NSMutableArray *links;
@end
```

### UnDigParser.m

Implementation for for parsing class:

```
#import "UnDigParser.h"

@implementation UnDigParser
NSMutableArray *_links;

@synthesize links = _links;

-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    _links=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"enclosure"]){

        NSString *link = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"];
        if (link){
            [_links addObject:link];
        }
    }
    //NSLog(@"%@",_links);
}

-(BOOL)parse{
    self.delegate = self;
    return [super parse];
}

@end
```

### ViewController.h

```
@class WebViewController;

@interface getpodViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *_podAllEntries;
    NSMutableArray *_allEntries;
    WebViewController *_webViewController;
}

@property(retain) NSMutableArray *podAllEntries;
@property(retain) NSMutableArray *allEntries;
@property(retain) WebViewController *webViewController;

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
@implementation getpodViewController

@synthesize podAllEntries = _podAllEntries;
@synthesize allEntries = _allEntries;
@synthesize webViewController = _webViewController;

-(void)addRows
{
    //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://undignified.podbean.com/feed"];
    UnDigParser *parser = [[UnDigParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];      

    [parser parse];
    [_podAllEntries insertObject:parser.links atIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"%@", _podAllEntries);

    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Podcasts";
    self.podAllEntries = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self addRows];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_podAllEntries count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _podAllEntries];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this:

```
 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_podAllEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

### Example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_podAllEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    /* to use less code, you can also do it like this: */
    //cell.textLabel.text = [_podAllEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

You can also remove the following statement from **`addRows`** since `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is where the cells will actually be created.

```
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Comment: I removed the [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths section and modified the NSString *cellValue as mentioned above. I still only have one row populating. Also, I have the tableView setup to NSLog out the selected row when clicked. Here is the output shows all items contained in the array. So, it's like the entire array is still thrown in the first row.

Comment: How many items are in your array? If only 1 item is showing up, then you only have 1 item in your array. If there are supposed to be more items in the array, then you are parsing your data wrong.

Comment: It appears I'm parsing the data wrong as the contents of the url Attribute are being loaded into the same entry.

Comment: Yes, so when you parse the data correctly, use the method I have explained above and you will see all of your items in your tableView.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! At least I know that portion is fixed and that the problem lies in adding items to the array. I'll try to figure that part out on my own.

Comment: I checked out the portion where the data is parsed and it turns out the items are being added as separate entries. It turns out NSLog will just print the entire array and separate it with commas thus making it appear as one item. So, I'm still stuck at just the 1 entry in the table. I've made the above changes so any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You did not understand how to build a UITableView in iOS.
You should populate your UITableView throughout the [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) Protocol.

You should read the Apple Info about [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageSelections/ManageSelections.html).

Don't use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` for adding the "main" rows.

Answer (score 0):

1. In cellForRowAtIndexPath, rather than `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _podAllEntries];` you should have `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_podAllEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`. That will make sure that each row of the table has a different row of your _podAllEntries array.
2. Jonas is right that you shouldn't be doing `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. The delegate methods you have defined take care of making sure everything gets added in.
3. How many items does you _podAllEntries have? It looks like: `[_podAllEntries insertObject:parser.links atIndex:0];` would add a single object, which is itself an array. Thus, you'd have only one row. I think you want `[_podAllEntries insertObjectsFromArray:parser.links]`.